# Programming Check Box in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, checkbox

I am programming a simple check box in MS Access. This is how it goes:

1. I have a combobox set up with a drop down of values the user can choose from.(e.g. b1, b2, c1, d1, d2, d3, e0, e2, etc) They are just 2 characters text string.
2. I have a checkbox to be used when the user wants to modify the value in the drop down. Basically all it does is, when the checkbox is checked, it will change any of the values to 'ds(drop down value)" so it just adds the "ds()". (e.g. ds(b1), ds(b2), ds(c1), etc)
3. If the user unchecks the checkbox, then the value stays as the 2 character text string.

This is my first foray into Access programming. My pseudo code is as follows:

```
Private Sub distchk_Click()
if distchk is checked then
   Me.ECOSITE = "ds(" & Me.ECOSITE & ")"
else:
   Me.Ecosite
End Sub
```

I tested:

```
Private Sub distchk_Click()
Me.ECOSITE = "ds(" & Me.ECOSITE & ")"
End Sub
```

but it keeps adding additional ds() anytime I check it, and won't remove it if I uncheck it.

Any suggestions would be great!

Mike

Comment: What is your intent here?  What you are proposing is certainly possible in Access but it sounds a bit...unorthodox...to say the least.  If you tell us your end goal we might be able to suggest a better way of getting there.

Comment: that is my end result. The user chooses something from the combo box which is just a classification of a vegetation land cover type. If the area has been disturbed, the classification gets a modifier (i.e. if the b1 unit is disturbed, it gets the ds() modifier, so ds(b1)). I simply want the user to check the checkbox and it adds the modifier. If they uncheck it, then I want the modifier to be removed.

Comment: It seems to me like you are doing some premature formatting of your data.  Separate data should be kept separate at the input phase (data entry form).  This will keep your UI cleaner and give you more flexibility when outputting your data (in reports, exports, etc.)  See my answer below for two alternative approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making unnecessary work for yourself and a more confusing interface for your users.  You are collecting two *discrete* pieces of data: LandCoverType (a Text field) and IsDisturbed (a Yes/No field, aka boolean or bit field) so I see no reason to combine them in an input form.  You are not providing the user with any additional information by wrapping the land cover types in "ds()".  I would suggest two alternative approaches:

**Two separate fields** *(preferred method)*

- create a LandCoverType field (Text); bind your combobox to this field (in the ComboBox ControlSource enter `LandCoverType`)
- create an IsDisturbed field (Yes/No); bind your checkbox to this field (same way as above)
- if you want to display the "ds()" on a report, then do that as part of the formatting of the report field (eg, `=IIf([IsDisturbed], "ds(" & [LandCoverType] & ")", [LandCoverType])`)

**One combined field**

- create a single LandCoverType field (text)
- change the RowSource of your combobox to include all of your LandCoverType's with and without the `ds()` (eg, if your RowSource is a value list: `b1, b2, c1, ds(b1), ds(b2), ds(c1)`)

Comment: Thanks mwolfe02. I am restricted to sue a per-designed database for a client. I don't have any flexibility over modifying it to fit something more desirable and something that actually makes sense. :( I managed to set the script to do this with my check box. Thanks for the suggestions. I like the approach and it may work with other projects.